# Python oneliner if condition with multiple statements separated with commas and semicolons

Tags: python, if-statement, one-liner

```
a = True

if a : print('msg1'), print('msg2');
# msg1 and msg2 are printed

if a : print('msg1'), print('msg2'), b = 1;
# if a : print('msg1'), print('msg2'), b = 1;
#       ^
# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

if a : print('msg1'); print('msg2'); b = 1;
# msg1 and msg2 are printed and b is also assigned the value 1

if a : b = 1; c = 5; print(b), print(c)
# b and c are assigned values 1 and 5, and both are printed
```

The 1st if statement works with the comma between the 2 print statements.
The 3rd if statement works as well with all statements separated with semicolons.

The 2nd if statement with a combination between commas and semicolons doesn't work anymore.
The 4th if statement with print statements separated by commas, and normal statements by semicolons works again.

So it seems to me that while print statments can be separated by commas, normal statements cannot. And thus it is better to just separate everything with semicolons in a oneliner if statement.

Could someone maybe explain / confirm the logic behind this?

Comment: You aren't seperating anything, you're joining the print statements together to create a tuple from their return values

Comment: The requirement to produce a one-liner is just pulling you deeper into the ditch. Breaking the statements over multiple lines is the obvious Pythonic solution and removes the need for elaborate footgunnery.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a, b` or `function(value), function(value)`, this is very different from `function(value); function(value)`. The comma effectively creates a tuple, whereas the semicolon separates statements. This is why the assignment works in the semicolon example but not the comma one:

```py
# this is the form of the comma statement
print('a'), b = 1

# raises a syntax error

# this is what the semicolon statements look like
print('a')
b = 1
```

The real fix: stop trying to write everything as one-liners. Compare the two statements:

```py
if a: b = 1; print('msg1'), print('msg2')

if a:
    b = 1
    print('msg1')
    print('msg2')
```

The second is easier to read and less cluttered. Just because it fits in one line doesn't make it better.